# Set key/values in array "cannot use a scalar value as an array"

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array var containing this data:

```
  $arr["values"] = [
    "key1" => "value1"
    "key2" => "value2"
    "key3" => "value3"
  ]
```

Now I'm trying to add new keys to `$arr` as follow:

```
$arr['newvalues'] = "anothervalue";
$arr['newvalues']['subvalues'] = "some_subvalue";
```

But I got this error:

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

And error is marked on this line:

```
$arr['newvalues']['subvalues'] = "some_subvalue";
```

Why? I'm not adding key/values properly? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `$arr['newvalues']` as an array to add elements to it, currently you are setting it as a string.

```
$arr['newvalues'] = [];
$arr['newvalues']['subvalues'] = "some_subvalue";
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
$arr['newvalues'] = "anothervalue";
```

You are assigning `$arr['newvalues']` a scalar value. On the very next line you are treating it like an array but it is not since you just assigned it a scalar value.

You *probably* mean to have `$arr['newvalues']` be an array and add `anothervalue` to it.

```
$arr['newvalues'][] = "anothervalue";
```